# При переходе с PHP 7.4 на PHP 8.1 возникла ошбка с PDO

Tags: php, pdo, execute

Подскажить что нет так. После того как перешёл на новую версию PHP 8.1 PDO начало выдовать ошибку синтексиса SQL но при это на PHP 7.4 всё работало. Не где не описаны новые изменения в PHP 8 по PDO.

Ошибка

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = 'home_page'' at line 1 in
```

```
public function query($sql, $values = [], $statement = PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
{

    $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);

    $sth->execute($values);

    $result = $sth->fetchAll($statement);

    if ($result === false){
        return [];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

`$this->link` - подключение к бд через PDO

Входные данные $sql является sql строка, а $value массив с параметрами.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM options WHERE key = ?";
$value = array('key');
```

Comment: Получается, что версия php тут не при чём?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте писать не значение сразу, а передавать именно переменные. Возможно `execute` работает именно с ссылками на переменные, а не чисто с массивом значений. Т.е. вместо

```
$value = array('key');
```

писать прмиерно так:

```
$myValue = 'test';
$executeValues = array($myValue);
$sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($executeValues);
```

---

Еще `key` может быть ключевым словом БД и поэтому название столбца лучше заключить в обратные кавычки

Comment: В метод query передаются данные sql запрос и массив с параматрами. Парамитры уже в сформированном массиве [1 => "key"].

Comment: Возможно что key ключевое слово я проверю.

Comment: @Lojje "парамитры уже в сформированном массиве [1 => "key"]" ---  ещё раз перечитайте что я написал и попробуйте

Comment: Всё благодарю! Оказалось что key нужно было ковычки.

Comment: Отлично, что помогло

Comment: @АлексейШиманский о каких ссылках речь? При `array($var)` никаких ссылок не возникает.